# How to split a columns as separate table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to split a column in my table as separate table in SQL Server. I currently have a table with data. I have a table with available courses for a program separated by semi column. I need to split this and keep it as two different tables as I need to search based on a course details.

Current table (`program_details`)

| program_code | course_available | start_date | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB;01;ERl;KL09;324 | 18-Sep-2022 | 1 |
| 2 | ER;02;EJl;DL09;414 | 14-Sep-2022 | 1 |
| 3 | JK;CD;201;PL08;201 | 28-Sep-2022 | 1 |
| 4 | FV;50;301;GL07;234 | 18-Oct-2022 | 1 |

I need to split this as two table for better searchability with course codes, I can write program for this or is there any easy way to achieve this using any functions of SQL Server?

Table `program_details`:

| program_code | start_date | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18-Sep-2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 14-Sep-2022 | 1 |
| 3 | 28-Sep-2022 | 1 |
| 4 | 18-Oct-2022 | 1 |

Table `program_course_mapping`:

| mapping_id | pgm_code | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AB |
| 2 | 1 | 01 |
| 3 | 1 | ER1 |
| 4 | 1 | KL09 |
| 5 | 1 | 324 |
| 6 | 2 | ER |
| 7 | 2 | 02 |
| 8 | 2 | EJ1 |
| 9 | 2 | DL09 |
| 10 | 2 | 414 |

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2016,

```
SELECT program_code
      ,A.value FROM #T T
CROSS APPLY(SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(T.Course_available,';')) A
```

Comment: Why use a `SELECT` in the `APPLY` and not just go straight to the function?

Comment: Since a table-valued function used SELECT @Larnu

Comment: But *why*? Why not `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T.Course_available,';') A`? Why `APPLY` to a subquery?

Comment: Was not sure about this way @Larnu. Will change it from next time.